# unable to read the package and display the dataset within the package when i select the dataset from the selectinput

Tags: r

I am unable to read the dataset of a package and display the content of it, i am trying to display the dataset content from 'dataset2' output.

I am using the libraries as mentioned in the code. I am able to see the content of the 'dataset1', only issue is with contents of 'dataset2'. Could you please help me how to resolve it

UI Part

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Package with datasets and functions"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput('pkg','Package Name', value = NULL),
            actionButton("update", "Update View"),
            helpText('Please enter the package name for which you want to see the list of datasets and functions (with parameters)'),
            br(),
            # br(),
            selectInput('dat','Datasets', choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            DTOutput("dataset1"),
            DTOutput("dataset2")
        )
    )
)
```

server part

```r
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pkgs <- reactive({input$pkg})
  # 
  # if (!is.null(pkgs())){
  df <- reactive({
  data_name1 <- data(package=input$pkg)
  data_name2 <- as_tibble(data_name1$results) %>% rename(name=Item, label=Title) %>% select(-LibPath)
  data_name2
    })
  # }


  obse <- eventReactive(input$update, { df() })
  
# if (!is.null(pkg1())){
  observe({
    req(obse())
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "dat", label = "Datasets", choices = c(df()$name), selected = df()$name[1])
    
  })
# }
  
  
  
  df2 <- reactive({
    req(obse())
    data(package = input$pkg)
    library(package = input$pkg)
    input$dat
    # new <- input$dat
    # data(new, package = input$pkg)
    # cat(new)
  })
  
  
    output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(obse())
    })
    
    output$dataset2 <- renderDataTable({
      df2()
    })
}

# Run the application 
# undebug(shinyApp)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `data`, we may need `list` and in `library` we can specify `character.only = TRUE`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Package with datasets and functions"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('pkg','Package Name', value = NULL),
      actionButton("update", "Update View"),
      helpText('Please enter the package name for which you want to see the list of datasets and functions (with parameters)'),
      br(),
      # br(),
      selectInput('dat','Datasets', choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("dataset1"),
      DTOutput("dataset2")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  pkgs <- reactive({input$pkg})
  # 
  # if (!is.null(pkgs())){
  df <- reactive({
    data_name1 <- data(package=input$pkg)
    data_name2 <- as_tibble(data_name1$results) %>% rename(name=Item, label=Title) %>% select(-LibPath)
    data_name2
  })
  # }
  
  
  obse <- eventReactive(input$update, { df() })
  
  # if (!is.null(pkg1())){
  observe({
    req(obse())
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "dat", label = "Datasets", choices = c(df()$name), selected = df()$name[1])
    
  })
   
  
  
  
  df2 <- reactive({
    req(obse())
    e <- new.env()
    library(package = input$pkg, character.only = TRUE)
    out <- data(list = input$dat, package = input$pkg, envir = e)
    e[[out]]
    
         
  })
  
  
  output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(obse())
  })
  
  output$dataset2 <- renderDataTable({
    df2()
  })
}
}

# Run the application 
# undebug(shinyApp)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you @akrun for your response, i accept your answer as solution, could you please let me know the purpose of the below steps                                                                                 
    e <- new.env()
    library(package = input$pkg, character.only = TRUE)
    out <- data(list = input$dat, package = input$pkg, envir = e)
    e[[out]]

Comment: @jkatam it is to assign the data to a new object and load it